# Opposite of Levi-Civita

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, fiber-bundles, connections, metric-geometry

I know that every Riemannian metric induces a unique connection.

**Question:**

My question is if the opposite direction is indeed true.  That is given a connection $\nabla$ on $M$ does there exist a Riemannian metric $g_{\nabla}$ on $M$ such that $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection for $g_{\nabla}$?

Comment: Short answer, yes. You must require that the connection be torsion free. After that, there is a characterisation of metric connections given by Schmidt that states that the linear torsion-free connection is metric if and only if the holonomy group is a sub-group of the orthogonal group of the desired signature.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for the fast answer.  Could I ask you for a reference Bacon?
Are you referring to this paper:
https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103858479

Comment: Yes that is the article

Comment: Excellent Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the torsion form of the Levi Civita connection is zero and this is not true for every connection.

See also the answer here for a connection whose torsion form is not zero.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133370/torsion-and-non-metricity-tensor-on-a-surface

A torsion free connection is not always a Levi Civita connection. See the answer of Thurston here for examples.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54434/when-can-a-connection-induce-a-riemannian-metric-for-which-it-is-the-levi-civita

A characterization of when a metric exits for a given Torsion free metric whose Holonomy group is a subgroup of $O(p,q)$ can be found here:
[Schmidt](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103858479)

Comment: If I restrict my attention to the set of torsion-free connections on $M$ then would each connection therein induce a Riemannian metric in a canonical way?  If so how?

Comment: Is your opening line directed to me, do we agree here? The condition that $\nabla $ is torsion free doesn't depend on a metric but the necessary and sufficient condition for $ \nabla $ to be a Levi-Civita condition is that its holonomy preserves at least one positive definite quadratic form, and that it is torsion-free.

Comment: The fact that the torsion vanishes is a local condition. The examples pointed in the second reference are connections which agree locally to Levi Civita connections so they are torsion free, but globally, there does not exist a metric which induces these connections.